# How do I enable the PHP agent on New Relic?

Tags: wordpress, newrelic, w3-total-cache

I've installed the New Relic PHP agent. My phpinfo shows that it's been installed. However on W3 Total Cache on WordPress, it still displays that that the PHP Agent is disabled. I have New Relic working fine for the server itself on their dashboard but also wanted to get it to display on WordPress dashboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely need to enable or view your New Relic API key and add it to W3 Total Cache plugin.

Log in to New Relic, go to:

Account Settings -> Integrations -> Data Sharing

Click 'Enable API Access'

Then copy and add the API key to your W3 Total Cache settings in WordPress:

In your WP Dashboard click plugins under W3Totalcache click Settings
Scroll down to monitoring and paste your API key in, do not forget to enable New Relic and set your application name.

Comment: If you're running multisite, remember that you can only change these settings if you're a Network Admin, and are in the Network Admin section.